# Thread 14 SwiftUI - Help to call an API and log in

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hello fellow Swift Coders. I'm a beginner, and i'm trying to call a web API then log in to have access to a new view.

This is my code, everything seems running well (before i try to put the login + pass)

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var loginSuccessful = false
     
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("primaryColor").ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        Text("FOLD")
                            .font(.system(size: 50))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                            .padding(.bottom, 80)
                    }
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 345, height: 400)
                            .cornerRadius(25)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("secondaryColor"))
                            .shadow(radius: 10, x: 10, y: 3)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Se connecter")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .bold()
                                .padding(.bottom,50)
                            

                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("Email")
                                    .font(.callout)
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                HStack {
                                    TextField("Enter email", text: $username)
                                        .padding()
                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("primaryColor"))
                                        .frame(width: 270, height: 50)
                                        .background(.white)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: 270, height: 60)
                            .padding(.bottom, 30)
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("Password")
                                    .font(.callout)
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                HStack {
                                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                                        .padding()
                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("primaryColor"))
                                        .frame(width: 270, height: 50)
                                        .background(.white)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: 270, height: 60)
                            .padding(.bottom, 50)
                            
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                logIn(username: username, password: password)
                            }) {
                                Text("Log in")
                            }
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 270,height: 40)
                            .background(Color("buttonColor"))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $loginSuccessful) {
                            QRscan()
                        }
                       
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
           
        }
    }
  
    func logIn(username: String, password: String) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://foldlab.io:8081/loginScanAccount")!
        
        let body = ["username": username, "password": password]
           
        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
                
                // Check if the login was successful
                if json["status"] as! String == "success" {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loginSuccessful = true
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error: Invalid username or password.")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, when i'm trying on the simulator or the preview, its crashing. And i have an error i've never seen.

What should i do ?

```
Thread 14: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}
```

Thanks a lot.

I tried to check on SOF, but i didnt really understand the answers

Comment: For starters, you should use `do { try ... } catch {print(error)}` blocks, not `try!` so you get better error info.  However in this case you already have an error message that tells you exactly what's wrong: `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set`.  Your response isn't JSON.

Comment: This is my JSON, i guess i have to make some structure, but i dont see how : {
    "error": null,
    "datas": {
        "user": {
            "_id": "blabla",
            "username": "user",
            "password": "password",
            "eventId": 0,
            "__v": 0
        },
        "token": "token"
    }
}